# Multiple Level of Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have the following Java class with multiple level of inheritance with certain type parameters. I want to use the type parameter T in class B.

```
class B extends C {
}
class C<T extends D> {
}
class D {
}
```

However, he following doesn't compile:

```
class B extends C {
    T t;
}
class C<T extends D> {
}
class D {
}
```

Although I can define the variable t in class C, but it is not a good coding practice. How can I define the following (This doesn't compile as well)?

```
class B extends C<T extends D> {
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "but it is not a good coding practice" 0o ? why ?

Comment: If I want to use this t for class B, but I get another subclass of class C, then I need to create a lot of variables t, t2, t3... in class C for all the subclasses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type parameters are not inherited!

If you want to have your class `B` generic, you should specify its own type parameter:

```
class B<T extends D> extends C<T> {
    T t;
    ...
}
```

Note that you must again constrain the type parameter `T` to have it extending `D` because it is constrained this way in class `C`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be :

```
class B<T extends D> extends C<T> {
}
```